# Best font for programming?

Tags: fonts

I am looking for the best font for not only programmers but all people which are "forced" to sit long hours in front of a computer and staring at screen. I expect less distraction, less eye tiredness, more readability etc. than anything casual/default.

Does exist some font with verifiable attributes suitable for usage during long hours programming / scripting?

Is Inconsolata a good choice?

Comment: Here's a huge thread on programming fonts over at Stack Overflow: [Recommended Fonts for Programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4689/1832306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain there is a "best" typeface. It's more about personal preference. The same way some prefer reversed text, some may have font preferences. Generally san-serif is thought to be easier to read on "on-screen" and a less-than-stark contrast setting can also be helpful.

I tend to lean towards a monospaced sans serif font such as Monaco. But I'm sure others may not like that font. I'm not familiar with Inconsolata , but it also appears to be a monospaced sans-serif typeface. I also prefer text at #333333 and a background at #eeeeee for coding.

Comment: Yes, I definitely agree with the fact that this is "personal taste" thing. However, is there any scientific research here? For example measurement of programmers performance in laboratory conditions? Just asking if you know about something accidentally :)

Answer (score 7):

Check this out: http://www.slant.co/topics/67/~what-are-the-best-programming-fonts
Seems like that both Inconsolata and Consolata are top choices for most coders.

Comment: Yeah, that's really great comparison page. I found Inconsolata 2 years ago while checking very similar comparison.

Answer (score 0):

None of the recommended fonts do it for me, I find them too 'lean' with too much white space wasted.

I personally use Lucida Console which comes with Windows. Compared to Consolas for same font size, the characters are taller which increases readability and lines are tighter resulting in being able to display 16% more lines.

The only caveat is that `0` and `O` are somewhat similar, so I created a version with a crossed `0` you can get [here](https://bitbucket.org/danielsokolowski/lucida-console-0-crossed/src/master/) or directly here

[image: Lucida Console with crossed 0]

Answer (score 0):

This is misc-fixed 6x13, from the X Window System.

Here is [a TTF for Windows](https://www.twoevils.org/files/fonts/MISCFS__.TTF), from April King's website, use it at 9pt.

[image: misc-fixed 6x13 example]