# Crisp Legible Font for Code Snippets

Tags: color, typography, contrast

I'm new to design, contrast and color concepts but I'm trying to get my programming code snippets to look crisp, clear and very legible, without hurting the eyes. I'm looking for a font that is ideal for programming code snippets in a blog. I'm looking for a free web safe font.

The background color of my page is almost white (#eee) and the code snippets will be wrapped in a  container with the following CSS details

```
<div class="code-snippets">

</div>


.code-snippets {
   background-color:#070707;
   color: eee;
   padding: 20px;
   /*   font-family: ??? */
}
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: We have a few similar threads that may help you: - On SO (Stack Overflow) there is a question titled: "[Recommended Fonts for Programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming)". - On GD (Graphic Design) there is a question titled: "[Best font for programming?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19007/best-font-for-programming)".

Comment: +1 Thank you for your reply. I'll check the links out.